# how to select specific part of command output based on some conditions using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am developing a script using python for my project. I want to select the free queues from the list of queues available to me. In linux terminal if I enter `bqueues -u $USER`, it is generating many fields out of them `QUEUE_NAME` and `PEND` tasks are two fields.

So I want to skip all queues having pending tasks and in remaining I want to select one randomly. I was able to select those to field using `awk` command but am unable to filter exactly free queue:

```
import os

list = []
list = os.system('bqueues -u ssudi -w | awk \'{print $1" " $9 }\'')

print(list)
print(list[1])
```

Assume we are entering following commands in linux terminal:

```
% os.system('bqueues -u ssudi -w | awk \'{print $1" " $9 }\'')
QUEUE_NAME PEND
a_queue 0
b_queue 1
c_queue 0
d_queue 4
e_queue 0
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

Any queue out of `a_queue`, `c_queue`, `e_queue`. Only the queue name is required.

Answer (score 0):

First, `os.system` won't return the output after executing the command. It is better to use the `subprocess` module for that. Second, you shouldn't use built-in names (such as `list`) as your variable names.

You can do something like the following (not tested as obviously I don't have `bqueues` installed on my system):

```
import random
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output('bqueues -u ssudi -w | awk \'{print $1" " $9 }\'', shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
queues = [row.split(" ")[0] for row in output.splitlines() if row.split(" ")[1] == "0"]
print("Available queues:", queues)
print("A random empty queue:", random.choice(queues))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./temp1.py", line 8, in <module>
    queues = [row.split(" ")[0] for row in output.splitlines() if row.split(" ")[1] == "0"]
  File "./temp1.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    queues = [row.split(" ")[0] for row in output.splitlines() if row.split(" ")[1] == "0"]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @user226751 Sorry, you are right. I should've added `universal_newlines=True` for Python 3.x. See updated answer.